# Is it possible to limit the number of ethers sent to a smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, ether, tokens, erc-20, ico

I'm a newbie in ethereum programming and is playing with an ICO smart contract. I want to know if it is possible to put the below restrictions in the smart contract:

1. Can I set a maximum amount for ether that can be send to the contract address over a 24-hour period? I want to make sure that a single user doesn't buy all my tokens.
2. Can I set a maximum amount of ether to be sent to the contract address over a 24-hour period? I want to make sure that only certain amount of my tokens are sold everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not prohibit people from sending Ether to a contract, but you can track the contrcact Ether-/Token -balance and send received Ether back once a cap is reached.
You should read a few contracts from [open Zepplin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts), its a great project to get a feeling for writing Smart Contracts. They have ressources in place, for use cases like yours.

To define Time intervals and check against them, there are two ways:
I)
You can use blocknumbers with "block.number".
II)
You can use timestamps with "block.timestamp" which returns a unix epoch

see here for [details](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html)

Comment: This is not correct, actually. You can revert transactions if certain amount of Ether has already been sent to the contract (with `receive` function, as mentioned in another answer). Similarily, you can connect that logic with a time-based logic

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `receive` function and has a `require` statement that makes the tx revert if `msg.value > someAmount`. More info in [the solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.2/contracts.html#receive-ether-function).